# Session persistent in apache LB configuration

Tags: linux, apache, session, load-balancing

I am configuring apache LB , where i faced a problem regarding the session persistence issue which i am not able to solve after trying multiple option.

Note this is not for web application, this is regarding my application server.

Below is the configuration i tried:

```
     <VirtualHost *:7802>

     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyPass /MenuMangement balancer://apacheLB
     ProxyPassReverse /MenuMangement  balancer://apacheLB
     Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" 
     env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED

     <Proxy balancer://apacheLB>
     BalancerMember https://xx.xx.xx.xx:7802/MenuMangement route=j1 
     loadfactor=50
     BalancerMember https://xx.xx.xx.xx:7802/MenuMangement route=j2 
     loadfactor=50

     ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic stickysession=ROUTEID
     ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic stickysession=ROUTEID
     </Proxy>
     </VirtualHost>
```

**Another option**

```
     ProxyPass "/test" "balancer://mycluster" 
     stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid scolonpathdelim=On
     <Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
     BalancerMember "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8595" route=node1
     BalancerMember "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8595" route=node2
     </Proxy>
```

Note: Try opening  jvm port on application tomcat and then route request on that port

Please suggest the way forward on this..

## Linux #Apache #loadbalancing

Comment: please help here..

Comment: Can anyone there to suggest on this issue please